# R get all combinations for columns and perform a function on them returning a Symmetric matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, apply, symmetric

I have a matrix `mat` that looks like:

```
      A     B     C     D      E     F
1  0.74  1.19  0.01  1.21  16000  0.02
2  0.76  1.17  0.01  1.21  15500  0.02
3  0.79  1.16  0.01  1.17  15625  0.02
4  0.75  1.17  0.01  1.17  15600  0.02
5  0.80  1.19  0.01  1.19  15225  0.02
6  0.79  1.18  0.01  1.18  15625  0.02
```

And I want to build a Symmetric matrix from this by applying the function `Sum(Col1-Col2)`. The end result will look something like this:

```
    A     B     C     D      E     F
A   0
B         0
C               0
D                     0
E                            0
F                                  0
```

Such that the blank spaces represent the sum of difference. i.e. `[1,2] = Sum(A-B)`.

I have investigated methods such as:

```
combs<-combn(names(mat),2)
val<-apply(combs,2,function(x) mat[[x[1]]]-mat[[x[2]]])
```

But it doesn't give me a nice symmetric matrix.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT - Thanks to Troy the above works. But how about if I want to compute `Sum((Col1-Col2)^2)` in that `Sum(((A_1,A_2,..,A_n)-(B_1,B_2,..,B_n))^2)` (so can't sum `A` and `B` initially and then subtract otherwise the answer will be off).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems valid, too:

```
outer(colSums(mat), colSums(mat), `-`)  #I used Troy's `mat`
#         A        B        C        D         E        F
#A     0.00    -2.43     4.57    -2.50 -93570.37     4.51
#B     2.43     0.00     7.00    -0.07 -93567.94     6.94
#C    -4.57    -7.00     0.00    -7.07 -93574.94    -0.06
#D     2.50     0.07     7.07     0.00 -93567.87     7.01
#E 93570.37 93567.94 93574.94 93567.87      0.00 93574.88
#F    -4.51    -6.94     0.06    -7.01 -93574.88     0.00
```

EDIT to match edited question:

```
n = seq_len(ncol(mat))
ff = function(a, b) sum((mat[,a] - mat[,b]) ^ 2)
outer(n, n, Vectorize(ff))
#             [,1]         [,2]        [,3]         [,4]       [,5]         [,6]
#[1,] 0.000000e+00 9.881000e-01 3.48390e+00 1.048400e+00 1459547504 3.393100e+00
#[2,] 9.881000e-01 0.000000e+00 8.16740e+00 2.100000e-03 1459471669 8.028000e+00
#[3,] 3.483900e+00 8.167400e+00 0.00000e+00 8.332500e+00 1459690004 6.000000e-04
#[4,] 1.048400e+00 2.100000e-03 8.33250e+00 0.000000e+00 1459469476 8.191700e+00
#[5,] 1.459548e+09 1.459472e+09 1.45969e+09 1.459469e+09          0 1.459688e+09
#[6,] 3.393100e+00 8.028000e+00 6.00000e-04 8.191700e+00 1459688132 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz, I edited the question so am in need of some further help! :)

Comment: Yep absolutely! That was it, thanks. I had just worked out a really roundabout and no doubt inefficient way of doing it. Your solution is much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
mat<-as.matrix(read.table(text="A     B     C     D      E     F
0.74  1.19  0.01  1.21  16000  0.02
0.76  1.17  0.01  1.21  15500  0.02
0.79  1.16  0.01  1.17  15625  0.02
0.75  1.17  0.01  1.17  15600  0.02
0.80  1.19  0.01  1.19  15225  0.02
0.79  1.18  0.01  1.18  15625  0.02", header=T))


cross<-expand.grid(apply(mat,2,sum),apply(mat,2,sum))
matrix(cross[,1]-cross[,2],6)

[,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6]
[1,]     0.00    -2.43     4.57    -2.50 -93570.37     4.51
[2,]     2.43     0.00     7.00    -0.07 -93567.94     6.94
[3,]    -4.57    -7.00     0.00    -7.07 -93574.94    -0.06
[4,]     2.50     0.07     7.07     0.00 -93567.87     7.01
[5,] 93570.37 93567.94 93574.94 93567.87      0.00 93574.88
[6,]    -4.51    -6.94     0.06    -7.01 -93574.88     0.00
```

for second question, how about this?

**EDIT - think I put the bracket in the wrong place**

```
apply(mat,2,function(x)colSums((matrix(x,ncol(mat),ncol(mat))-mat)^2))
#             A            B           C            D          E            F
#A 0.000000e+00 9.881000e-01 3.48390e+00 1.048400e+00 1459547504 3.393100e+00
#B 9.881000e-01 0.000000e+00 8.16740e+00 2.100000e-03 1459471669 8.028000e+00
#C 3.483900e+00 8.167400e+00 0.00000e+00 8.332500e+00 1459690004 6.000000e-04
#D 1.048400e+00 2.100000e-03 8.33250e+00 0.000000e+00 1459469476 8.191700e+00
#E 1.459548e+09 1.459472e+09 1.45969e+09 1.459469e+09          0 1.459688e+09
#F 3.393100e+00 8.028000e+00 6.00000e-04 8.191700e+00 1459688132 0.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thank @Troy. Now if I want to do `Sum((A-B)^2)`, how would I go about doing it? I think the main issue here is that I can't sum `A` and `B` then subtract initially, I need to do this operation on EACH row of each column. So something like `Sum(((A_1,A_2,..,A_n)-(B_1,B_2,..,B_n))^2)`. Thanks!